# Convert Web Page from Swedish to English in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use the below code to convert a web page from Swedish to English language:

`chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en-US")`

I also tried the below:

```
            'profile.default_content_settings.images': 2,
            'translate_whitelists': {
                'se':'en',
                'el':'en',
                }, 
            'translate':{'enabled':'True'}, 
            'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US',
             })
```

None of them worked. The code has to be in Python Selenium

Comment: Is this link useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016300/selenium-change-language-browser-chrome-firefox

Answer (score 0):

Try below code -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

browser_locale = 'en'
chrome_driver_path = 'chromedriver.exe'

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--lang={}".format(browser_locale))

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path,
                           chrome_options=options)
browser.get('https://google.com/')
```

Make the changes as it suits you.